Identical IDs Returned Every 32 Inserts in Milvus Client - Is My Code at Fault?
I'm using the Milvus client to insert data into a collection, but I've noticed that the IDs returned in the result are identical for every 32 inserts, with the 33rd insert returning a different ID. Is there something wrong with my code, or could this be a configuration issue?
  const result = await client.insert({
    collection_name: DatasetVectorTableName,
    data: [
      {
        vector,
        teamId: String(teamId),
        datasetId: String(datasetId),
        collectionId: String(collectionId),
        createTime: Date.now()
      }
    ]
  });

  console.log("result1234", result)

  const insertId = (() => {
    if ('int_id' in result.IDs) {
      return `${result.IDs.int_id.data?.[0]}`;
    }
    return `${result.IDs.str_id.data?.[0]}`;
  })();

  return {
    insertId: insertId
  };

Is this code wrong?

You do not provide enough information for your question.
